# Как в эмуляторе на Android Studio подключить микрофон с ПК?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
// Скачивал специально приложения с Play Market для проверки звука, но микрофон не работает.
// Моя программа должна узнавать частоту звука, но возвращает (-1) то есть звук не считывает.

 AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);
        PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult res, AudioEvent e){
                final int pitchInHz = (int) res.getPitch();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        processPitch(pitchInHz);

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        AudioProcessor pitchProcessor = new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, pdh);
        dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(pitchProcessor);

        Thread audioThread = new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Thread");
        audioThread.start();
```